# Int[] Java issue

Tags: java, int

So I am trying to do a tutorial island quest for my game, and here is the error I come upon with.

```
if (StagesLoader.forId(player.getNewComersSide().getTutorialIslandStage()) != null)
                player.getActionSender().enableSideBarInterfaces(
                              StagesLoader.forId(player.getNewComersSide().getTutorialIslandStage()).getSideBarEnabled()[StagesLoader.STAGE_2]);
```

Here's my ActionSender Class.

```
public void enableSideBarInterfaces(int[] listSideBar) {

            int[] sidebars = { 2423, 3917, 638, 3213, 1644, 5608, 1151, -1, 5065,
            5715, 2449, 904, 147, 962 };
    for (int i = 0; i < listSideBar.length; i++)
            {
           sendSidebarInterface(listSideBar[i], sidebars[listSideBar[i]]);
    }
}
```

Here's my stagesloader enum, and class.
http://pastebin.com/TVCUSRKr

Here's the error:!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/atwGb.png

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are using an enum, where the code expects an int[]. 
Try adding the enum to an int[], or restructure your code to allow for the enum values instead of expecting an array.

Comment: int[] x = new int[1];
x[0]=2;

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you whats wrong. Obviously this construct

```
StagesLoader.forId(player.getNewComersSide().getTutorialIslandStage()).getSideBarEnabled()[StagesLoader.STAGE_2]
```

returns a simple `int`, but the method you are passing it into requires an `int[]`

Answer (score 0):

Clean this up a little. Don't mess too much code into one line. Particularly, you could split the lines in question into

```
ID id = player.getNewComersSide().getTutorialIslandStage();
StagesLoader stagesLoader = StagesLoader.forId(id);
if (stagesLoader != null)
{
    int sideBar = stagesLoader.getSideBarEnabled()[StagesLoader.STAGE_2];
    int sideBars[] = new int[]{ sideBar };
    player.getActionSender().enableSideBarInterfaces(sideBars); 
}
```

The problem is that the method expects an `int[]` array, but you tried to pass a single `int` value. You can, however, put this single `int` value into an array, and then pass this array to the method.

Comment: Thanks, but how should I construct it?

Comment: I's already in my answer: `int sideBars[] = new int[]{ sideBar };`

Comment: Still confused about this.

Comment: This line creates a new `int[]` array. This `int[]` array is called "sideBars". This `int[]` array only contains a single value. Namely the value "sideBar". Maybe have a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html